# Javascript how to read file content on a subdirectory

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html

I'm implementing directory upload on my web application, I wrote the code to traverse the directory being uploaded and to build the list of files under such directory

```
var traverseFileTree = function(item) {
    if (item.isFile) {
        item.file(function(file) {
            alert(file.name);
        });
    }
    else if (item.isDirectory) {
        var dirReader = item.createReader();
        dirReader.readEntries(function(entries) {
            for (var i=0; i<entries.length; i++) {
                traverseFileTree(entries[i]);
            }
        });
    }
}

var items = event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.items;
for (var i=0; i<items.length; i++) {
    var item = items[i].webkitGetAsEntry();
    if (item) {
      traverseFileTree(item);
    }
}
```

problem is, the `file` object only contains the filename and file length, no byte array is provided. How can I get the file content at this stage?

Comment: It is not recommended to use non-standard features of browsers because of their unpredictable behavior

Comment: @MysterX ok, could you please tell me how Dropbox achieve such thing?

Comment: Well, I had not found any possibility to upload folder within dropbox web dashboard, only files. Can you share a link where I can see it?